# No Gigabit Speed option on Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller Alienware 17 R3

Tags: networking, ethernet, network-adapter

Any suggestion to get my Gigabit options back on the speed & duplex settings for my NIC. Drivers are up to date but only Auto, 10Mbps FD, 10Mbps HD, 100Mbps FD & 100Mbps HD show in the Card Advanced tab. Already checked the switch port and it works correctly at 1000Mbps with another computer.

Any advice, help is really appreciated.

Comment: For what possible reason would you want to do this?!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot choose speed and duplex settings on a Gigbit connection. It must be auto-negotiated. There is only full duplex in Gigbit mode.

The auto-negotiation algorithm (known as NWay) determines the master-slave interlock between the physical interfaces at the ends of the link. This mode is necessary to establish the source of the timing control.

This was mandated by the 1999 standard for Gigabit over copper cabling, IEEE Std 802.3ab:

```
Mandatory auto-negotiation for 1000BaseT
Configure master and slave modes for the PHY
```

This is why you don't see the settings. Just leave it on auto and never touch it again.